# foreman smart-proxy unable to communicate

Tags: unix, puppet, theforeman

I've installed foreman on an existing puppet master via the `foreman-installer` and can now login via the GUI and can see the smart proxy is running by going to the `https://xx.xx.xx.xxx:8443/features` page which lists:

`["puppet","puppetca","tftp"]`

So this indicates the proxy is running but when I try and add the IP and port number to the foreman smart proxy page I get this error:

```
Unable to communicate with the proxy: ERF12-2530 [ProxyAPI::ProxyException]: Unable to detect features ([SocketError]: getaddrinfo: Name or service not known) for proxy https://xx.xx.xx.xxx:8443/features
Please check the proxy is configured and running on the host.
```

I've got the entry for the master in the `/etc/hosts` file as IP and FQDN. It's also set in `puppet.conf`.

Since the foreman-proxy is running on the same server as foreman and the puppet master I've enabled http connectivity in the proxy settings and now adding the smart proxy is successful with `http://localhost:8000` but gives `ERF12-5356 [ProxyAPI::ProxyException]: Unable to get PuppetCA certificates`

Is there more setup I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

> getaddrinfo: Name or service not known) for proxy https://xx.xx.xx.xxx:8443

Though you've solved this, it suggests to me that there could be a typo in the IP address and it's being resolved as a name rather than a literal IP. It's hard to tell with the obfuscation.

Otherwise, Foreman's log (/var/log/foreman/production.log) may show more details with a stacktrace.

> ERF12-5356 [ProxyAPI::ProxyException]: Unable to get PuppetCA certificates

The smart proxy log file (/var/log/foreman-proxy/proxy.log) should indicate the reason and have more details. You may want to increase the `log_level` verbosity to debug under /etc/foreman-proxy/settings.yml temporarily.

The Puppet CA smart proxy module does require sudo rules to be set up - the installer will usually do these, but if you installed manually, check them against https://theforeman.org/manuals/1.12/index.html#4.3.7PuppetCA.

Answer (score 0):

i found having a double /etc/host entry was enough to cause this